# RSpec View testing with Rails3 and RSpec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, webrat

RSpec2 does not include an `have_tag` test helper. Using webrat's `have_tag` or `have_selector` matchers  instead is not possible because Webrat and Rails 3 are not compatible yet. Is there a way to write useful **RSpec view tests**? It is possible to use `assert_select` instead of `have_tag`, but then one could `Test::Unit` tests in the first place. Or is it no longer recommendable to write RSpec view tests, because integration tests with Capybara or Cucumber are better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webrat caused too much trouble, it is also possible to use Capybara with RSpec. The Capybara DSL (with the functions `has_selector?`, `has_content?`, etc.) is available for the following RSpec tests: `spec/requests`, `spec/acceptance`, or `spec/integration`.

If you use the latest version of Capybara (~> 1.0.1) - older versions like 0.4.0 won't support this - and add the following lines to your `spec_helper.rb` file

```
require "capybara/rspec"
require "capybara/rails"
```

then you could write for example the following RSpec request test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Posts" do
  describe "GET /blog" do
    it "should get blog posts" do
      get blog_path
      response.status.should be(200)
      response.body.should have_selector "div#blog_header"
      response.body.should have_selector "div#blog_posts"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Webrat works with Rails 3. I have tested this and I was able to use the have_selector matcher (have_tag didn't work).

You can take a look at this [Google group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/webrat/browse_thread/thread/d4b5d43ca2975842/8d1b9f7e1fa0a08b). Basically, you don't need the Webrat.configure block mentioned in the webrat readme, and following the mailing list solution, add these lines in your spec_helper.rb:

```
include Webrat::Methods
include Webrat::Matchers
```

As you can see, Webrat is not so updated anymore, so yes, you might be better off with integration testing with Cucumber (+ Capybara).

Comment: Does it work only with the version mentioned there, '>=0.7.2.pre', :git => 'http://github.com/kalv/webrat.git' ?

Comment: @0x4a6f4672, I didn't notice that in their discussion before, so I just used the regular flavor of webrat. I basically just added `gem 'webrat'` in my Gemfile.